# Google Chrome Messaging API between scripts not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that grabs a page, searches for an item, then buys it. I am able to grab the page, but when I message my content script, nothing happens.

I've tried messaging the content script from both my background script and my popup.js file.

```
//message sent from background script 
chrome.tabs.query(
    {currentWindow: true, active: true},
    function(tabArray){
        tabs = tabArray;
        let msg = {
            action: "runSearch"
        };
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabArray[0].id, msg);
});
```

```
//content script receiving end
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.action == "runSearch"){
        alert("message recieved"); //this alert never appears
        };
};
```

I expect the output to be an alert that says: "message recieved",
but the actual output is nothing.

Comment: Your code works, check that you have the "tabs" permission, that the message is really being sent and that the content script is running on the page.

Comment: Your problem is that the content script isn't running at the time you're sending the message. The background script runs in a separate hidden background page which runs independently of content scripts so you need to put the code into an appropriate event listener. The question doesn't show how your content scripts are declared in manifest.json so we can only make guesses. It's not even clear why you need a background script at all.